# Best way to handle seperate code versions in visual studio 2015

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I'm overhauling an application with Visual Studio 2015 Community Version using the Team Foundation Server (not git) for source code management.

I want to replace the forms by newer versions one by one over time. However, each the development of the new forms takes quite some time. Now I wonder, what the best way is, to deal with cases like: new version of module 1 is only at 50%, but I have to fix an error in the initial version. Obviously, I don't want to roll out the 50% version.

I figure there are some ways, like branching. But I couldn't find a way to switch between the different branches. Is there a good guide or any other lead on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is the branch. Since you are using TFVC instead of git, so you can’t switch branch like git.

You just need to map these branches to different folders, then you can do work with them directly. (Open solutions in multiple Visual Studio instances)